# questions on prototype WSO2 API Manager to Work as a JMS Producer

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to prototype the two patterns describe in the article on "How to Enable WSO2 API Manage to Work as a JMS Producer" 
http://wso2.com/library/articles/2015/10/article-how-to-enable-wso2-api-manager-to-work-as-a-jms-producer/

I am having following issues and questions:
1. I am getting exceptions when creating a mediation following the step 3 in "Pattern 1: WSO2 API Manager as a JMS Consumer". When select the ‘Browse’ icon in the Resources tab, I got blank screen with following error.  I am using IE browser. Java env is JDK8.

*[2016-01-17 22:23:36,275] ERROR - RoleSecurityTagSupport IO Error executing tag: JSPException while including path '/res
ources/resource.jsp'. ServletException while including page.
java.io.IOException: JSPException while including path '/resources/resource.jsp'. ServletException while including page*.

2. This article uses ActiveMQ as an example. I am trying to use an existing IBM Websphere MQ instance installed on my local laptop. 
   for Pattern 1, can it apply to Websphere MQ instead of ActiveMQ without EMB in between?  If yes, what are the the configuration steps?

Answer (score 0):

Its not recommended to use the sequence editor on the web browser to define your sequences. You should either use WSO2 Developer Studio to create your sequences or any other XML editor.

However, on a different thread [1] I have seen that you have reported this issue and got it resolved by using API Manager 1.10.0. Was it a different issue or the same?

[1] - [Create Mediation Exception In WS02 API Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34863578/create-mediation-exception-in-ws02-api-manager)

Comment: yes, it's the same issue. I created a new one just to be clear.

Comment: I am having another issue of validating JMS URL while creating the API in this exercise. I have a question is posted at:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34957558/how-to-debug-invlide-jms-url-while-creating-an-api?s=2|2.8969