# Create Mediation Exception In WS02 API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am having following issues and questions: 
 I am getting exceptions when creating a mediation. When select the ‘Browse’ icon in the Resources tab, I got blank screen with following error. I am using IE browser. Java env is JDK8.

[2016-01-17 22:23:36,275] ERROR - RoleSecurityTagSupport IO Error executing tag: JSPException while including path '/res ources/resource.jsp'. ServletException while including page. java.io.IOException: JSPException while including path '/resources/resource.jsp'. ServletException while including page.

Comment: The full Exception message is as follows:

Answer (score 0):

Could you please specify the API Manager Version?

We don't support JDK8 for API Manager versions released until API Manager 1.9.1. However we support JDK8 in the API Manager 1.10.0

Therefore if you are using a version which is APIM 1.9.1 or older, please downgrade JDK to JDK 1.7

For References:

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM191/Installation+Prerequisites - API Manger 1.9.1
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Installation+Prerequisites - API Manager 1.10.0

Comment: Thanks. I had v1.9.1. Just downloaded v1.10.0. Yes, it worked with jdk8