# How to debug invlide JMS URL while creating an API

Tags: wso2

I am following an example to do the following:
"Create an API with the JMS backend endpoint – Let’s now create an API within the API manager. You can follow the regular process when creating the API. As shown below, make sure you enable ‘POST’ HTTP verb when defining the resources.

Once this has been done, let’s add the JMS URL as the production endpoint. Select the endpoint type as ‘Address Endpoint’ from the endpoint type drop-down menu. The production URL would be the actual JMS endpoint. The JMS URL for an ActiveMQ message queue should something like this:

jms:/DataFeed?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&java.naming.provider.url=tcp://localhost:61616&transport.jms.DestinationType=queue

In this case, the queue name is ‘DataFeed’, and Queue URL is localhost with port number 61616."

When I use the "Test" button to verify the URL. I get "invalid" but not sure what's not valid. I have DataFeed queue created in activeMQ and assume other variables are standard by using default values in activeMQ.   Any idea how to get more meaningful message?

Answer (score 0):

AFIK this is the current behavior, URL tests only available for the http/https endpoints and for the other transport (like jms,RabbitMQ) seems this option not correctly work.

Even though, test option giving the "invalid" message you can check the URL functionality by sending a message using the API, then check whether the message correctly enqueue.

Comment: OK. however, when I tried to created an API following the pattern specified in the following article

Comment: Did you try to enqueue a message? If  any problems there, then we have to consider on URL parameters.

Comment: Sorry, hit return before I typed all my words.  I am using API console to test. the API published does POST with payload. it shows the parameter content type:application/json.  so I was trying a simple one like :
{
    "test": "a test message"
}

when hit "Try it out" button, got exception:
[2016-01-24 22:38:52,942] ERROR - NativeWorkerPool Uncaught exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.getMessageFormatter(Lorg/apache/axis2/context/MessageContext;)Lorg/apache/axis2/transport/MessageFormatter;

any advice on this exception?

Comment: Did you follow this document http://wso2.com/library/articles/2015/10/article-how-to-enable-wso2-api-manager-to-work-as-a-jms-producer/